# Tableview did select need picker view in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I would like to show picker view on `UITableView` method `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. This is a sample design (i need custom picker which display food name instead of date and time). NumberOfRowsInSection is more than 10. When cell is selected picker view will display and select values from picker view. How can i achieve this?

[image]

Comment: you can use the library: https://github.com/hijamoya/PickerViewCell

Answer (score 0):

Implement in your TableViewController the UIPickerViewDataSource & UIPickerViewDelegate protocols with the following methods:

- *numberOfComponentsInPickerView* (# of columns in the picker view, probably 1 for your case).
- *pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent* (# of rows to display, probably your data array count).
- *pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:* (height of each row in the components, I think there is a default value in case it is not implemented, but you might want to change this anyway).
- *pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:* (the title, in case you only want to show text for each component, this is very similar to "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method in TableViews).

In case you want to present the data in a more personalized way, instead of "titleForRow" implement:

- *pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:*

For event handling when the user selects a row in the picker implement:

- *pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:*

**Remmember to** set the delegate of the UIPickerView to 'self' when created (this will be inside a cell of a TableView, so you have many options to create it, either create a prototype cell in the storyboard with a UIPickerView inside or manually in the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath') and conform to those protocols in the header file of your TableViewController.

To implement the switch from regular TableViewCell in the TableView to the cell with the interactive UIPickerView you might want to have the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" in the TableViewController to refresh that cell, you can use [self.tableView reloadData] or with a nice animations using:

- *reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:*

For example, you can have a BOOL variable called 'editingPickerView' set up initially to 'NO' and inside 'didSelectRowForIndexPath' method have this:

```
if(indexPath.row == X) {
   self.editingPickerView = !self.editingPickerView;
   [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
}
```

I use storyboards, so I would have a prototype cell for normal data showing (no UIPickerView) and when selected show a different prototype cell.
Meanwhile, in the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' you need to have a different way to provide the same row depending on the 'editingPickerView' variable, somewhat like this:

```
if(editingPickerView) {
   //reuse the cell with the identifier 'UIPickerView_cell'
   UIPickerView *picker = (UIPickerView*) [cell viewWithTag:69];
   picker.delegate = self;
} else {
   //reuse the normal cell with the identifier 'normal_cell' and show data
}
```

If you want to change to normal cell when the users selects a row in the UIPickerView inside the pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent: you should do something like this:

```
self.editingPickerView = !self.editingPickerView;
//you should probably know 'a priori' what index path your picker would be in
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: Just updated the answer to show how to do the transfer from "normal_cell" to "picker_cell", remember to put a tag to the UIPickerView inside the prototype cell so you can access like the example does. You can easily find thorough explanations on every method I suggested with sample code on the API Documentation inside Xcode (CMD+Shift+0).

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden Textfield to your view. Then in viewDidload:

```
self.dtmPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.dtmPicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[self.dtmPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(DateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.lblDate.inputView = self.dtmPicker;
```

I'm using this. It's so easy :)

Comment: But i need to display in tableview

Comment: You can add textfield in cell.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Just replace UIDatePicker with UIPicker control & add appropriate delegate methods. URL:  http://masteringios.com/blog/2013/10/31/ios-7-in-line-uidatepicker/3/

I think this what you want. Just remove "UIColor+Custom.h", "UIColor+Custom.m" & its references to get ride of errors.

URL: https://github.com/wannabegeek/PickerTableViewCell

Comment: Ya..i got this project. in that project i need VCPeopleViewController for desgin. but checking there make issues to do my desgin. how to do this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Can you elaborate which design you are talking about?. So I can try.

Comment: i want to do the first screen. didselect the tableview and select the date in the picker.